# VBA degree character not recognized in worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, character

I am using excel vba on a windows 10 computer.
I want refer to a worksheet whose name is "20°C". I have given the name 20°C manually and I can see it at the bottom of the sheet.
However, when I refer to the page through this code line

```
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("20°C")
```

I get the error "Subscript out of range".
I have also tried:

```
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("20" & Chr(176) & "C")
```

and

```
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("20" & ChrB(176) & "C")
```

but I still get the error.

If I read the name property of the worksheet with this code line

```
ActiveCell = Worksheets(2).Name
```

I get the cell value 20°C.

Finally if I eliminate the character ° from the name (so I use the name 20C instead) I get no error.

CONCLUSION: the character ° is creating the error.

QUESTION: is there any way to refer to the worksheet by its name when it contains a degree character (°)?

Comment: How do you write the respective character when naming the sheet, respectively, when write the sheet name in VBA? Did you try `Alt + 0176`? Did you insert a Symbol font character? If I write it using  `Alt + 0176` in both cases, I can set the sheet having the respective name.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. If `ThisWorkbook` is different from the workbook containing `ActiveCell`, it would explain your differing results.

Comment: correct, better if you paste some more surrounding coding to solve your issue

Comment: Refers the sheet with index, e.g. if it is the first sheet in workbook, `Debug.Print Asc(Mid(Sheets(1).Name, 3, 1))` the result may not 167.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome Thanks, very clever hint. I tried your suggestion and I got code -15696. I took for granted that the ° character I inserted manually corresponded to ascii extended code 176 but I was wrong; for some reason I ignore, excel decided that the code is -15696. That solves my issue

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks, your comment is useful. My conclusion is that characters that you see on the screen can have more that one code, as in this case ° corresponds to extended ascii 176 or to DBCS -15696. Pls see also my comment to taller